# How to deploy Health Check in IIS as a Web App+WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, health-check

I have built a HealthCheck app using nuget package (https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks)

I persist the Health probe status response in a Singleton object and expose it via my own custom Controller/Action method as a REST API. I did this to decouple the Health Check API Endpoint and abstract Health Check core services from external consumers.

Now coming to the issue. I want to deploy this Health Check App so that it will run as a background service as well as be queryable via my Custom WEB API REST Endpoint + Health Check API Endpoint.

Please share some ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

healthcheck:
test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost/api/ping"]
start_period: 60s

Comment: While deploying I need to make the Rest API endpoint domain based not localhost cos if we use localhost, it cant be called by external apps.